# Tampermonkey how to use it on two different websites

Tags: javascript, crosstab, tampermonkey

I got question like this, how to get information from one web url for example and use it in another url

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @version      0.1
// @grant    GM_setValue
// @grant    GM_getValue
// @grant    GM_openInTab
// @grant    GM_SuperValue
// @include       https://tynachofinder.ge/*
// @include       https://tynachofinder.ge/finder/*
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js
// @require https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/107941.user.js
// ==/UserScript==

GM.setValue("discord", document.querySelector(".site-btn").innerText);

document.querySelector(".header-section.clearfix").innerHTML = (
    GM.getValue("discord")
);
```

something like this how to make it working

Comment: What are the results you are expecting, what happens instead? Your code seems missing an `if (location.href==...)` before the get/setValue-statements.

Answer (score 0):

To make a Tampermonkey script match multiple websites, you can use the @match directive to specify the web pages that your script should run on. The value of @match should be a URL pattern that matches the pages you want your script to run on. Here are the parts of the URL pattern that you’ll need to set:

```
@match <protocol>://<domain><path>
```

For example, if you want your script to run on all pages of example.com, you can use:

```
@match https://example.com/*
```

If you want your script to run on all pages of example.com and example.net, you can use:

```
@match https://example.com/* https://example.net/*
```

If you want your script to run on all pages of example.com and its subdomains, you can use:

```
@match https://*.example.com/*
```

If you want your script to run on all pages of example.com and its subdomains, and also on all pages of example.net, you can use:

```
@match https://*.example.com/* https://example.net/*
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.